# Connecting to Swagger Client using Azure in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, swagger

We have 3 cleints namely- TestingClient, ITestingClient and ITestingClientExtension. Ideally we would like to assign a variable in our winform. In order to assign the variable we declared

TestingClient client = new TestingClient(new Uri("https://rserver.contoso.com:12800")); We get an error stating delegation handler is protected. How do we establish this connection. Thank you

TestingClient.cs begins with this:

````
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// The base URI of the service.
/// </summary>
       public Uri BaseUri { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets json serialization settings.
       /// </summary>
       public JsonSerializerSettings SerializationSettings { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets json deserialization settings.
       /// </summary>
       public JsonSerializerSettings DeserializationSettings { get; private set; }        

       /// <summary>
       /// Subscription credentials which uniquely identify client subscription.
       /// </summary>
       public ServiceClientCredentials Credentials { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of the TestingClient class.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name='handlers'>
       /// Optional. The delegating handlers to add to the http client pipeline.
       /// </param>
       protected TestingClient(params DelegatingHandler[] handlers) : base(handlers)
       {
           this.Initialize();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of the TestingClient class.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name='rootHandler'>
       /// Optional. The http client handler used to handle http transport.
       /// </param>
       /// <param name='handlers'>
       /// Optional. The delegating handlers to add to the http client pipeline.
       /// </param>
protected TestingClient(HttpClientHandler rootHandler,params DelegatingHandler[]handlers):base(rootHandler,handlers)
       {
           this.Initialize();
       }```
````

Comment: @shreyas how did you generate this client class? Was it AutoRest/VS "Add Rest Client" function?

Comment: @CaiusJard Hello Thank you for responding. I added it through the REST API Client. The json link was provided from https://microsoft.github.io/deployr-api-docs/9.2.1/swagger/mlserver-swagger-9.2.1.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you should use one of the public constructors rather than your current attempt to use one of the protected ones. Here's a screenshot (with public constructors in yellow) from a recent client I generated for that APIs, in the same way yours was generated ("Add REST Client").

[image]

For example, your code will need to look more like

```
Uri u = new Uri("https://rserver.contoso.com:12800")
ServiceCredential sc = ...create a relevant credential...
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ fill it in
TestingClient client = new TestingClient(u, sc);
```

Comment: Okay. This worked until the service credential part. We do not have a credential and it throws an error to establish the initializer. Is there a way to create service credential without any service credentials? 
Also we get non-static error for u,sc

Comment: *We do not have a credential* - this probably represents the single biggest barrier to successfully using a service that requires credentials

Comment: Okay. Was able to connect it. Had to create an Anonymous Credential. Used this for reference.https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/visual-studio-2017-swagger-building-documenting-web-apis/